# How to create a secure PHP Web Service for access by iOS App

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out how to properly connect an iOS app to a MySQL database.  I have the following code in my Model.

```
import Foundation

protocol HomeModelProtocol: class {
func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class HomeModel: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

//properties

weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocol!

let urlPath = "http://hourofswift.com/service.php" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives

func downloadItems() {

    let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
    let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

    let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to download data")
        }else {
            print("Data downloaded")
            self.parseJSON(data!)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

}

I have the PHP Web Service set up.  That file is on the web server and has the credentials to access the database.  What I am confused about is what I do if I don't want my database to be public.  The iOS app is hitting the PHP Web Service and requires no credentials from the iOS app.  That means anyone with an internet connection could send requests to the PHP Web Service.  What do I do if I don't want the database to be public?

Comment: Require some form of credentials

Comment: Also interested in this if anyone can offer some more information.